# How to get the value from another dataframe that is in list of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

Data1

| store | value | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 | 1 |
| 1 | 28 | 2 |
| -------- | -------- |  |

Data 2

| store | month |
| --- | --- |
| [1, 2, 3] | 1 |
| [2] | 2 |
| -------- | -------- |

I need to add values from the column value to the second table based on conditions:
month from the table 1 must match the month in the table 2
store from the table 1 must be in list of the stores in the table 2
I also need to display the minimum of the value. So if there are several stores in the column store of the second dataframe, I need to add the minimum value among them.

| store | month | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1, 2, 3] | 1 | 24 |
| [2] | 2 | 0 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- |

I've tried lambda function, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

you must provide a clear example.

i edit your example

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'store': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'value': [24, 28, 29, 0], 'month': [1, 2, 1, 2]}
data2 = {'store': [[1, 2, 3], [2]], 'month': [1, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df1:

```
    store   value   month
0   1       24      1
1   1       28      2
2   2       29      1
3   2       0       2
```

df2:

```
    store       month
0   [1, 2, 3]   1
1   [2]         2
```

---

**Code**

use `explode`

```
s = df2.explode('store').reset_index()\
       .merge(df1.groupby(['store', 'month'], as_index=False)['value'].min(), 
              how='left')\
       .groupby('index')['value'].min()
out = df2.assign(value=s)
```

out

```
    store       month   value
0   [1, 2, 3]   1       24.0 <-- 1 is 24, 2 is 29 so min is 24
1   [2]         2       0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two datasets are in two dataframes df1 and df2.

Start by first merging the two datasets,

```
merged = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='month', how='left')
```

Define a function to get the minimum value from the 'value' column;

```
def get_min_value(row):
    if pd.notna(row['store']):
        return min(df1[df1['store'].isin(row['store'])]['value'])
    else:
        return 0
```

Apply this function the each row in the merged data dataframe;

```
merged['value'] = merged.apply(get_min_value, axis=1)
```

Dropping other columns;

```
result = merged[['store', 'month', 'value']]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).